# Grafana OSS OnCall can't connect to Grafana-Cloud

Tags: grafana, grafana-on-call

I installed Grafana and Grafana OnCall on my Server via docker compose.
But now when i try connecting the local OnCall with the Grafana-Cloud OnCall i just get the error 'Invalid Token', the `docker logs` also doesn't show anything interesting.

I am using the default [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/grafana/oncall/blob/dev/docker-compose.yml) from the github repo.
I tried setting 'GRAFANA_CLOUD_ONCALL_API_URL' as env for OnCall but it's still not working and not showing up in the Settings page.
Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.
The trick is to add `GRAFANA_CLOUD_ONCALL_API_URL` as env for **Grafana**.
And also not as full URL only 'https://oncall-prod-eu-west-0.grafana.net/oncall' is needed.